# Custom title bar not filling the screen

Tags: android, android-titlebar

I have a custom title bar for my app.

**I edited values/styles.xml to make my title bar 45dp. (below)**

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">

    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->

</style>


<style name="CustomTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">45dp</item>
</style>
```

**This is my layout for the custom title bar (below)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/background_gradient"
android:gravity="center_vertical" >

<ImageView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="7dp"
    android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
</ImageView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="7dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>

</ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is my drawable for the background color i set for the RelativeView above**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

<gradient
    android:type="linear"
    android:centerX="49%"
    android:startColor="#FFFF6417"
    android:centerColor="#FFffffff"
    android:endColor="#FFFF7308"
    android:angle="315"/>

</shape>
```

**Android manifest file:**

```
android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
```

---

**In each activity I am doing this**

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.notice_main);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title_bar);
```

I believe that I have done everything correctly.

**Yet I am getting this. I do not know why.**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your Layout for the custom title bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@drawable/background_gradient">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/info_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/info_icon" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/info_icon" >
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Brontok...sorry for late reply I had to ready the app for client demo....anyway I pasted your code but still I get the grey strips......I also noticed that grey strips are present all around the screen....http://imgur.com/kunnhJI

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the actvity full screen, means no default title bar and after that set the custom title bar. by doing this the gray portion will be removed

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.notice_main);

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title_bar);
```

After this you can set the padding from left and right margin properly

Comment: I did this exactly as you wrote. I get **android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features**

Comment: put this in the layout only with framlayout

Comment: I put my relativelayout inside a framelayout. Framelayout is set to fill parent width and height. I do not get exception now but the UI stills looks like the above picture.

Answer (score 0):

Better create following code in style.xml in values

```
<style name="WindowTitleBackground">     
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/titlebar_backgrnd</item>   
</style>
```

And the following code in theme.xml in values

```
<style name="customTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">30dip</item> 
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>
</style>
```